# Bulk upload of Microsoft Word files to WordPress pages

Tags: wordpress, ms-word

I have been asked to upload 200 Microsoft Word documents — many of them containing lengthy, complex math problems or scientific notation — into a WordPress setting. Each Word file would become a separate WordPress post.

I would clearly prefer to not cut-and-paste each file one-by-one into a post and then save it . Does anyone know of a way to automate the process while ensuring the accuracy of the translation, or at least minimizing the number of issues we might find when converting from Word to WordPress? Or am I dreaming the impossible dream?

Thanks for any input you can offer.

Comment: Would a PHP solution help you in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an interesting problem.  I have an idea that might be worth exploring.  There are [a number of free or shareware tools](https://www.google.com/search?q=batch%20word%20to%20html%20converter&aq=f&oq=batch%20word%20to%20html%20converter) that can convert Word docs to HTML.

If you can manage to convert them into decently clean markup with one of those tools, I would recommend using the [HTML Import 2](http://wordpress.org/plugins/import-html-pages/) WordPress plugin.  It can take a batch of HTML files and create Posts / Pages out of them.

It's a two step process, but I bet it'll work.  (And certainly be faster than copy/paste 200 times).

Hope that helps, have fun!

Comment: Sounds promising, Jared. I had looked at the possibility of converting all the Word files to LaTex, a math notation system that apparently WordPress does handle well, but I had not found a suitable way yet to get the files into LaTex. I never thought of going through html.  I'll check some of those possibilities. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well I got the solution which works for me, but its bit manual but still save a lots of time.

Here are the Steps.

1. Connect your Blog to Ms word 2007/2013
2. Make sure Remote writing is Enabled in WP
3. Copy all post in one Word document or use merge to make one single DOC.
4. Now Set Default posting category from WP and Save it.
5. Now from your MSWORD copy the post and start posting one by one.

Tips:
Make Shortcut key for publishing.
Use Ctrl+C for text before publishing. 
Make shortcut for publishing to WP